# How to make the contents in a directory to be downloaded as a ZIP file using PHP?

Tags: php, zip

I have lots of files in a particular Directory. In a certain PHP page I lists the contents of the particular directory with links to download each item separately. Now I need to display a Link which will ZIP all the contents of that directory so any visitor can download all the contents as a Single ZIP file.

Comment: Do you want a PHP-script that creates a zip-file of the content in the directory?

Comment: You can check this out: http://davidwalsh.name/create-zip-php
Or du you can take a look at the other answers which is kinda the same solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ZipArchive](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) for zipping files and [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) for getting all files in a directory

something like

```
$zipfilename = <zip filename>;
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open($zipfilename, ZipArchive::CREATE);
// add all files in directory to zip
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('path/to/files/')) as $filename) {
    $zip->addFile($filename);
}
$zip->close();
```

Then send the zip to the browser

```
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'. $zipfilename .'"');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipfilename));
readfile($zipfilename);
```

Obviously you could post the directory name and event the zip file name to the script but it gives you a starting point

Comment: Is there any option to remove the ZIP file when a user finish downloading it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$files = array('file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt');
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open('file.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($files as $file) {
  $zip->addFile($file);
}
$zip->close();
```